# Adding new functionality to a non extendable class java

Tags: java, function, inheritance, final

Is the a way to add a new functionality to a non extend-able class i.e(final class ) in Java , I know a way to add a property to it using `HashMap` .for example if i have a `Widget` class that declared `final`  and i want to add a new property to it lets say  'serial code' then i can you the `HashMap` to add it like this

```
serialHashMap.put(widgetObject,serialNumber);
```

so is there a way to add new functionality to a final class , any suggestions ??? thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't add anything to the object in question; it assumes a reasonable hashCode/equals, and *associates* the data with the object.

You could use the same methodology and something resembling a command pattern to associate an interface implementation with the object.

Your best bet might be to composite the object into your own class, though. Only your code will be able to utilize the new functionality, so it might as well be encapsulated.

(I'm ignoring things like adding interfaces through byte-code manipulation, proxies, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what type of functionality you want to add, but can you use the "typeclass" pattern? Comparator is an example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html